# How do you send a campaign to a custom channel in pinpoint?

Tags: aws-pinpoint

I've created a separate "custom channel" in AWS Pinpoint using the [example documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/channels-custom.html) (beta), but the campaigns I send don't match any endpoints.

I've updated the project to use my Lambda function:

```
aws pinpoint update-application-settings \
    --application-id  my-pinpoint-id \
    --write-application-settings-request '{\"CampaignHook\": { \"LambdaFunctionName\": \"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:my-application-id:function:MyLambdaFunction\", \"Mode\": \"DELIVERY\" }}'
```

... and I've created a segment with various endpoint ChannelTypes, e.g. `SMS`, 
`EMAIL`, `APNS`, `GCM`, `CUSTOM`.  But when I send anything to that channel via the Console no notifications get sent---it says "Endpoints targeted 0".  I thought that all endpoints would go through my Lambda function....

Any idea how to send something to a segment via a custom channel?

Comment: I see that my endpoint with a CUSTOM ChannelType didn't get added to the segment via upload. 
I took the status string from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/apireference/apps-application-id-endpoints.html.  Regardless, I don't see how this is supposed to work.

Comment: Same here :/ I added a CampaignHook to application, but custom channel does not show up in the list of channels. Did you have any success with it @mikebridge?